# What does --ascii option do for zip command?

Tags: zip

In Mac OS X 10.5,

```
 $ man zip
```

shows

```
  -a
    --ascii
           [Systems using EBCDIC] Translate file to ASCII format.
```

and

```
 Info-ZIP                      16 June 2008 (v3.0)                      ZIP(1L)
```

What does it mean?

If I want to revision control some `.zip` files using `git` and `hg`, what options should I consider using with `zip` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the description says, it's only for computers that use EBCDIC. If you've never heard of EBCDIC, that won't apply to you. i.e., don't bother using `--ascii`.

If you're curious, [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) is a family of character encodings that are totally incompatible with ASCII, used on some IBM systems.

Comment: In fact, it is a family of character encodings, much like the ISO-8859 encodings are a family of encodings based on ASCII.

Comment: So, if I need to version control some text (containing unicode characters) files in secure way, so some one having access to the remote server where the central repository resides couldn't see the content of the files, what should I do?

* I can `zip -e` these files and commit it to repository on remote server, but will it mess up or work badly with `git`?

* Encrypt the text files using `gpg -output foo.txt.gpg --encrypt foo.txt` and commit `foo.txt.gpg` to remote server. But the ASCII text in the .gpg file will have no meaning to be version controled. What should I do then?

Comment: @Computist: I don't know how to help you with that question. You should ask a new question! Other people may be able to help better.